# Add placeholder to bootstrap selectpicker

Tags: jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I have created a bootstrap selectpicker. But I want to show a place holder called **Search here** inside select picker input search. It seems my methods are not working.

I tried with this script. It doesn't seem to affect

```
$(".selectpicker").selectpicker({
  liveSearchPlaceholder: "Placeholder text"
});
```

Anyone know any solutions, please?

The snippet:

```js
$(".selectpicker").selectpicker({
    liveSearchPlaceholder: "Search here.."
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.3/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.14/dist/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.14/dist/js/bootstrap-select.js"></script>

<select class="selectpicker" data-show-subtext="false" data-live-search="true" style="-webkit-appearance: none;"  data-live-search-placeholder="Search" >
    <option value="" disabled selected class="disabled"></option>
    <option value="ExhibitionPreparation">Exhibition Preparation</option>
    <option value="Onlineserviceorderplatformandformssubmission">- Online service order platform and forms submission</option>
    <option value="StandconstructionMachineandExhibitsetupmatters">- Stand construction. Machine and Exhibit set up matters</option>
</select>
```

Comment: can you describe better what is your issue?

Comment: The place holder in the search input was not showing. But thanks to you I updated to the latest bootstrap-select.

Answer (score 2):

i found this example "bootstrap-select with placeholder" try so: https://codepen.io/yakyrefael/pen/XRmVRG

```
<select class="selectpicker" multiple data-live-search="true" data-live-search-placeholder="Search" data-actions-box="true">
              <option>option1</option>
              <option>option2</option>
              <option>option3</option>
              <option>option4</option>
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup label="filter2">
              <option>option1</option>
              <option>option2</option>
              <option>option3</option>
              <option>option4</option>
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup label="filter3">
              <option>option1</option>
              <option>option2</option>
              <option>option3</option>
              <option>option4</option>
            </optgroup>
</select>

$('.selectpicker').selectpicker(
  {  
    liveSearchPlaceholder: 'Placeholder text'
  }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Please, replace this code

```
$(".selectpicker").selectpicker({
   liveSearchPlaceholder: "Placeholder text"
});
```

by this one:

```
$(function() {
   $(".selectpicker").parent('.bootstrap-select').find('.filter-option-inner-inner').text('Search here..')
})
```

You can change ".selectpicker" by the id of a select if you want to set to it a specific placeholder.